# select the sum of every client's last order

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, group-by, sum

My data is as follows:

```
ORDER_ID   CLIENT_ID   DATE     VALUE
        1881    51  2010-07-19  100.17
        1882    50  2010-07-19  100.17
        2754    50  2010-07-25  135.27
        2756    50  2010-07-25  100.28
        5514    50  2010-07-27  121.76
        5515    50  2010-07-28  109.59
        5516    50  2010-07-27  135.29
        5517    50  2010-07-28  121.77
        5518    50  2010-07-31  123.15
        5519    50  2010-07-31  123.16
        5520    50  2010-07-31  109.62
        6079    51  2010-07-31  100.33
        7372    50  2010-07-25  100.27
```

What I want is to specify an initial date, for example, '2010-07-27', to filter only records at or after this date in the WHERE clause; the query should get the latest order from client 50 (order 1881) and client 51 (order 5516) and sum them together. I know it's simple and I tried in some different ways but couldn't find the right path. I guess I'm thinking narrow today, so I'm turning to you for help.

Thank you.

Comment: I really appreciated every one of your answers, and wish to express my sincere gratitude for your helpful time.
Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's give this a try:

```
SELECT CLIENT_ID, SUM(VALUE)
FROM YourTable
WHERE DATE >= '7/27/2010'
GROUP BY CLIENT_ID
```

Unless I've misread or misunderstood your question. :)

Edit: Let's try this, given the feedback:

```
SELECT SUM(VALUE)
FROM MyTable mt,
(SELECT CLIENT_ID, MAX([DATE]) AS 'Date'
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY CLIENT_ID) AS r
WHERE mt.CLIENT_ID = r.CLIENT_ID
AND mt.DATE = r.Date
```

Edit again: Basing last order on ORDER_ID instead of DATE:

```
SELECT SUM(VALUE)
FROM MyTable mt,
(SELECT CLIENT_ID, MAX([ORDER_ID]) AS 'ORDER_ID'
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY CLIENT_ID) AS r
WHERE mt.CLIENT_ID = r.CLIENT_ID
AND mt.ORDER_ID = r.ORDER_ID
```

Comment: sorry, I wasn't clear. Your query gives me the last order of each client. I want to sum every last order together.

Comment: Sorry Lynx, I've updated the answer with what should work (when recreating your table and data locally). Please let me know how it goes!

Comment: @JasonA: +1 as a welcome to SO :)   I think for this example your query would still sum all orders from the same day (5518, 5519, 5520)

Comment: it sums all the values from orders 5515, 5517, 5518, 5519, 5520, 6079.

Comment: in fact, it sums 5515,5517,5518,5519,5520 and 6079
= (

Comment: Hi guys - Andomar, thank you! Lynx - The challenge here is that your date column doesn't have hours included, so in my query's case it pulls in the other orders as well. Let me re-edit my answer with what should be appropriate.

Answer (score 2):

I would prefer not using a subquery as they can slow a query down as the table gets larger...

how about this:

```
SELECT SUM(VALUE) AS SumOfOrderValues
FROM
    YourTable t 
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT CLIENT_ID, MAX(ORDER_ID) AS MaxOrderId
        FROM YourTable
        WHERE [DATE] >= '2010-07-27'
        GROUP BY CLIENT_ID
    ) AS m ON m.MaxOrderId = t.ORDER_ID
```

This should give you this latest order for each client on or after a certain date. Then the SUM of the Values for the specific orders.

Comment: +1 Welcome to SO.  If you think a subquery is slow, read the execution plan; most `not exist` clauses are actually run as if they were joins.

Comment: Thx Andomar, I mentioned subqueries after seeing wllmsaccnt's solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a subquery to filter orders for which no later order exists, like:

```
select  sum(t1.value)
from    YourTable t1
where   t1.Client_ID in (50, 51)
        and t1.Date > '2010-07-27'
        and not exists
        (
        select  *
        from    YourTable t2
        where   t1.Client = t2.Client
                and 
                (
                    t1.Date < t2.Date
                    or
                    (t1.Date = t2.Date and t1.Order_ID < t2.Order_ID)
                )
        )
```

A `group by` is not required if you only select the sum.

Your comment suggests you're looking for the FIRST (not latest) order after 2010-07-27.  If that's the case, replace the subquery condition with:

```
                (
                    t1.Date > t2.Date
                    or
                    (t1.Date = t2.Date and t1.Order_ID > t2.Order_ID)
                )
```

Comment: Thanks, but the result from this sum isn't what is expected. Putting ORDER_ID instead of the sum() function, I see that the function summed orders 5518, 5519, 5520 and 6079 - it should sum only orders 5516 and 1881. It's all fine before the AND NOT EXISTS.

Comment: @Lynx Kepler: Edited: now if there are multiple orders with the same date, it selects the one with the highest order number.  The `not exists` is to filter for the latest order; if you'd like to sum all orders after 2010-07-27, leave the entire clause out.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT

SUM
(
  (SELECT TOP(1) VALUE
   FROM ORDER
   WHERE
   CLIENT_ID=C.CLIENT_ID
   DATE >= @LBOUND_ORDER_DATE
   ORDER BY DATE DESC
  )
) AS TotalLatestOrders

FROM

CLIENT C
```

Comment: Nice, but it only returns the last order (ORDER_ID = 5516) from the first customer (CLIENT_ID = 50). In this case, I must obtain the last order from each customer (50, 51...)

Comment: It is summing the corelated subroutine.  It should only return one value, and that value is the sum of the value of each client's most recent order.

Answer (score 1):

why 1881 and 5516 ? I think the last order for this 2 client are 5520 and 6079.
below is mine:
select sum(value) from (
select value, row_number() over (partition by client_id order by order_id desc) as sn
from 
tablename where date > '2010-7-27'
) T where sn = 1

Comment: client 51 has 2 orders: 1881 and 6079. But only 1881 was before the date '2010-07-27'. The same for client 50

Comment: put <= instead of > you will get what you need. I guess i misread your question..